# jQuery Slider Doesn't Work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

My code works perfectly with all browsers except IE. I tried every solution I could find on the forums with no luck. I am still learning JavaScript, so I will learn jQuery later. The issue is that in IE the slides appear vertically with no effect. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <link href="stylesheet...css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title>div test</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider({
                controls: false
            });

            $('#bx-prev').click(function () {
                slider.goToPreviousSlide();
                return false;
            });

            $('#bx-next').click(function () {
                slider.goToNextSlide();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="slider1">
        <div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="head"><img alt="logo" align="left" src="logo.png"/></div>
                <div id="main"> <div id="content">content</div> </div>
                <div id="rash"><img alt="r" align="middle" 
                                    style="position:relative;top:-70px;" 
                                    src="image1.png"/></div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="head"><img alt="logo" align="left" src="logo.png"/></div>
                <div id="main"> <div id="content">content</div> </div>
                <div id="rash"><img alt="r" align="middle" 
                                    style="position:relative;top:-70px;"
                                    src="image1.png"/></div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>page3</div>
        <div>page4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bx-next">next</div>
    <div id="bx-prev">prev</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my style sheet:

```
div#head {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    /*background-color:antiquewhite;*/
    margin-bottom:100px;
}

div#content {
    border-left: 2px solid #F0F8FF;
    border-right: 2px solid #8a815d;
    border-top: 2px solid #8a815d;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #8a815d;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 28px 20px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 28px 20px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 28px 20px 0px;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#8a815d;
    padding-left:100px;
    background-color:#F0FFFF;
    background-color: rgba(215,227,211,0.3);
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:0px
}


div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div#main {
    /* background-color:black;*/
    width:50%;
    height:360px;
    float:left;
}

div#rash {
    float:right;
    /*background-color:blue;*/
    height:360px;
    width:50%;
}

body {
    background-color: #E8F3F9;
    background-image: url('squares layer.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}

/*next button*/
#bx-next {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    right:3px;
    z-index:998;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -999999px;
    background: url(gray_next.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;
}

/*previous button*/
#bx-prev {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    left:4px;
    z-index:998;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -999999px;
    background: url(gray_prev.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;
}
```

Comment: do you have any errors in the console? can you post your code on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: it says your JS code is valid

Comment: i think you have not implemented a correct html structure for this plugin... make sure you follow the steps for implementing this plugin.. check http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am also having a similar problem, and I have not yet come to the conclusion but from what I have figured out so far is that to debug this problem you should start out by validating your code.  http://validator.w3.org/  I copied your code and it said you had 5 errors so I think a start would be fixing these errors because IE is very picky and if you have any errors if could effect your formatting.  Also I know that IE is picky about the Doc Type at the top of your code and if it is not correct it can also effect the formatting of the page.  If I can get my similar problem fixed I will let you know because it is most likely the same problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="wrapper">` is defined twice. An ID needs to be unique for every element on your page. Same goes for `<div id="head">`, `<div id="main">`, `<div id="content">` and `<div id="rash">`.

Also, have you tried debugging it in the IE console? Try and see if the console logs any errors at runtime. Then get back to SO and post those errors.

Cheers.